# Auto Layout Orientation does not working

Tags: ios, rotation, orientation, autolayout, portrait

I have a trouble with auto layout orientation. Simply i'm pushing view controller to take control from rootVC with this line of code

```
    fooBar *foo = [[fooBar alloc]initWithNibName:@"fooBar" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:foo animated:NO];
```

My fooBar view controller has auto layout so i should be able to get landscape orientation when i turned phone but phone still remaining to be in portrait mode.

Also strange part is i debug and methods below does not working to.. (i put them to fooBar VC)

```
(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
return YES;
}
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
//returns true if want to allow orientation change
return TRUE;
}
```

build options Ios SDK 6.0, Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the navigation controller doesn't forward those method calls. If you want it to, you will need to create your own custom navigation controller and follow this pattern:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

So in summary, create your own concrete implementation of UINavigationController, and then forward the above two methods to whatever view controller is currently visible. You should then notice those methods being called in your fooBar class.

Comment: i've tried what you said in new project by pushing FooVC from navigation controller and than **it worked**. it seems navigation controller handle orientation stuffs. But it didn't work in my main project sadly. My project is older (it was iOS 5) and we're trying to immigrate to auto layout, so maybe thats why..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Orientation settings]

Please check in the project settings whether you have these orientation checked.

Comment: yes i didn't miss device orientation options from both plist and general options.